# Error Ajax al cargar tabla

Tags: php, ajax, html5

Estoy intentando hacer una tabla para editar los campos con tabledit pero siempre me da el mismo error al cargar la tabla y no me muestra los registros... parece que es un problema en el archivo fetch.php pero no logro conseguir mostrar registros. El error que da siempre es DataTables warning: table id=sample_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7,

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
var dataTable = undefined;
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(dataTable) dataTable.destroy();

    var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500], [25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500]],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kopieren',
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Drucken'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                text: '<i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF'
            }
        ],
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "order" : [],
        "ajax" : {
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
        }
    });

    $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
        $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
            url:'action.php',
            dataType:'json',
            columns:{
                identifier : [0, 'id_expediente'],
                editable:[[1, 'objeto'], [2, 'numero']]
            },
            restoreButton:false,
            onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                if(data.action == 'delete')
                {
                    $('#' + data.id).remove();
                    $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });
        
}); 
</script>
```

```css
<style>
            /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
            .navbar {
              margin-bottom: 0;
              border-radius: 0;
            }
            
            /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
            .row.content {height: 450px}
            
            /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
            .sidenav {
              padding-top: 20px;
              background-color: #f1f1f1;
              height: 100%;
            }
            
            /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
            footer {
              background-color: #555;
              color: white;
              padding: 15px;
            }
            
            /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
            @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
              .sidenav {
                height: auto;
                padding: 15px;
              }
              .row.content {height:auto;} 
            }
        </style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
        
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</h3>
   <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Sample Data</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
 </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

//action.php

include('dbcon.php');

if($_POST['action'] == 'edit')
{
 $data = array(
  ':objeto'  => $_POST['objeto'],
  ':numero'  => $_POST['numero'],
  ':id_expediente' => $_POST['id_expediente']
 );

 $query = "
 UPDATE expedientes 
 SET objeto = :objeto, 
 numero = :numero,  
 WHERE id_expediente = :id_expediente
 ";
 $statement = $con->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
 echo json_encode($_POST);
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'delete')
{
 $query = "
 DELETE FROM expedientes 
 WHERE id_expediente = '".$_POST["id_expediente"]."'
 ";
 $statement = $con->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 echo json_encode($_POST);
}


?>

<?php
include('dbcon.php');
// fetch.php
/*$query_expedientes = 'SELECT * FROM expedientes';
$result_expedientes = mysqli_query($con, $query_expedientes);
$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_expedientes))
{
$output[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($output);*/
$column = array("id_expediente", "objeto", "numero");

$query = "SELECT * FROM expedientes ";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE objeto LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR numero LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id_expediente DESC ';
}
$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $con->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount(); 

$statement = $con->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row['id_expediente'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['objeto'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['numero'];
 $sub_array[] = $row['decreto_firma'];
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($con)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM expedientes";
 $statement = $con->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'   => intval($_POST['draw']),
 'recordsTotal' => count_all_data($con),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'   => $data
);


echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste la guía del [enlace que proporciona datatables](http://datatables.net/tn/7)?

Comment: Hola... sí lo he revisado y no le saco punta.

Comment: el archivo fetch.php da HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: ¿Te fijaste en el servidor qué error arroja? ¿Revisaste si en la consola del navegador muestra algún mensaje adicional? ¿Estás realmente haciendo bien la petición?

Comment: Invalid JSON response... es el error que está dando

Comment: Exactamente da un alert --> DataTables warning: table id=sample_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Fijate entonces el formato de JSON que está devolviendo. Si lo que está devolviendo es un array, entonces no olvides agregar el atributo `dataSrc: ''`, tal como indica [la documentación](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location). ¡Controlá siempre qué devuelve el servidor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido dar con el problema. Todo estaba después de hacer la conexión con la BBDD... Tenía que poner `$con->exec("set names utf8mb4");`
De esta manera funciona todo perfecto.

Comment: el problema que tengo ahora es que no actualiza los registros... cuando le doy a editar, me llega a mostrar el registro editado en la tabla pero al refrescar la página no se han guardado los cambios

Comment: ¿Se _commitean_ los cambios?

Comment: Exacto... lo anterior funciona pero he observado que no guarda cambios. Consola me da success pero no cambia nada... parece que no hace nada el UPDATE

Comment: Verificá si se commitean los cambios que hacés. Puede que el autocommit esté en false. En todo caso, depurá tu código y revisá que efectivamente se estén haciendo los cambios en el servidor, imprimiendo en consola el resultado del update (generalmente devuelve cuántos registros se modificaron).

Comment: Está comprobado, de hecho tengo mysql abierto para ir viendo si hace algún cambio en la tabla y por lo visto salta el update o no procesa bien. onSuccess imprime success.

Comment: Te sugiero que depures de nuevo, y si en verdad no estás encontrando respuestas, creá una nueva pregunta con un [repro]. Los comentarios son efímeros, y no son para _chatear_, si no para pedir o dar aclaraciones. En todo caso, podés preguntar en [la sala de chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol).